# How to get the dynamic category link in custom query from specific category

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

To get my requirement I used below code...

```
<div class="home_single_item_headline">
     <?php query_posts('post_type=post&category_name=Browser&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=6&paged='. get_query_var('paged')); ?>
     <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/category/<?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->category_nicename; ?>">Browser</a>                        
</div>
<div class="home_single_item_column floatleft">    
    <?php get_template_part('post-loop')?>
</div>
```

but I get the category link randomly means other category link. What will be the proper solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should use get_category_link($category_id).

So in your case you would have:

```
<?php $category = get_the_category(); ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category[0]->term_id); ?>">Browser</a>
```

Comment: Ok, then try this:

<?php 
$categories = get_the_category();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
if ($category->name == "Browser"){$link = get_category_link($category->term_id);}
}
?>

And then use <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">Browser</a>